# How to call a method when self.iface.actionSelectRectangle().trigger() is released?

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, pyqt4

In my QGIS python plugin I use `self.iface.actionSelectRectangle().trigger()` to select features. I also have a button which changes the attributes of the selected features.

Is there a way instead of using a button to change the attributes, to call the method automatically after a selection was made using `self.iface.actionSelectRectangle().trigger()`.

Answer (score 2):

An answer is here : [How to define an event for features selected in mapcanvas in qgis using python](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/139823/how-to-define-an-event-for-features-selected-in-mapcanvas-in-qgis-using-python)

You can connect your function to the `selectionChanged` signal of your vector layer

Example code from the related answer:

```
lyr=iface.activeLayer()
def myFunction(selFeatures):
   print str(len(selFeatures)) + " features were selected: " + str(selFeatures)

lyr.selectionChanged.connect(myFunction)
```

Each time you change the selection of your vector layer, `myFunction` is run.