# Adding dynamic text feedback for QGIS plugin?

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins

I am building a plugin using Qt Designer which will initially allow users to select features for a chosen polygon layer and then when a feature is selected on the canvas, the area is printed out in some sort of display widget.

For comparison, the **Coordinate Capture** tool (shown on the left in the image below) allows users to select on canvas and then print the coordinates in the boxes shown.

[image: Plugins]

**How could I connect selecting features on canvas to displaying the area in the text browser?**

---

I am using the following guides for reference:

- [Creating the UI and first logic](http://nathanw2.github.io/dmsnz-pyqgis-workshop/addingui/)
- [Building a Python Plugin](http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/building_a_python_plugin.html)

---

The following is what I have in code so far. If I move the code from `print_area()` to `run()`, I can print the total area in the text browser. But can't seem to connect it correctly so that whenever a layer is chosen from the combo box, the text browser get's updated.

```
def run(self):
    layers = self.iface.legendInterface().layers()
    layer_list = []
    for layer in layers:
        self.dockwidget.comboBox.clear()
        self.dockwidget.show()
        layer_list.append(layer.name())
        self.dockwidget.comboBox.addItems(layer_list)
        selectedLayerIndex = self.dockwidget.comboBox.currentIndex()
        selectedLayer = layers[selectedLayerIndex]

def print_area(self):
    for feat in selectedLayer.getFeatures():
        geom = feat.geometry()
        self.dockwidget.textBrowser.setText(str(geom.area()))

    selectedLayerIndex.selectionChanged.connect(run)
```

Comment: I don't have a full answer, but the connection (between feature selection and area display) would be done using a Python signal. See [there](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/139823/how-to-define-an-event-for-features-selected-in-mapcanvas-in-qgis-using-python) for a specific example and [there](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/new_style_signals_slots.html) for general info about PyQt signals.

Comment: @ArMoraer - Thank you for the links, they look interesting! Will give them a thorough read :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use a Line Edit widget.

Inside your `run()` function put something like:

```
self.selectedLayer = self.iface.activeLayer() # Adjust this to your situation
self.selectedLayer.selectionChanged.connect( self.printSelectedArea )
```

Then define your `printSelectedArea` function:

```
def printSelectedArea( self ):
  area=0
  for f in self.selectedLayer.selectedFeatures(): 
    area += f.geometry().area()
  self.dockwidget.txtArea.setText( str( area ) )
```

Note that this will print the selected area of your currently selected layer. You would need to adjust the code if you want to add areas across layers, which I didn't see from your question.

When a user chooses a layer in your `comboBox` you should disconnect the `printSelectedArea` slot from the previous selected layer and connect it to the new one. You could also disconnect the `printSelectedArea` slot from any `SIGNAL` when your plugin is closed or unload. Otherwise, you would end up messing `printSelectedArea` calls up.

Additionally, you would need to add conditionals to make sure there is a `selectedLayer` before calling `selectedFeatures()`.

Comment: Thanks, will give this a go! Can I ask why choose a line edit instead of a text browser?

Comment: Mainly because `QTextBrowser` is best suited for hypertext. For instance, you could print Internet links there and the user could interact and click on them. In this case you just need to print a 'raw' text line, which is what the `QLineEdit` is for. It's just about using the minimal widget that fulfils your requirement. A `QTextBrowser` would give much more than you need in this particular use case.

Comment: Good to know, many thanks! Will see how far I get with this ;)

Comment: Sorry but just a minor follow-up question: to disconnect the `printSelectedArea` slot, could I use something like`self.selectedLayer.selectionChanged.disconnect( self.selectedLayer, self.printSelectedArea )`?

Comment: You could use: `self.selectedLayer.selectionChanged.disconnect()`, which will disconnect any slot connected to that signal, or just pass the slot as argument: `self.selectedLayer.selectionChanged.disconnect( printSelectedArea )`. Non-selected layers should have no connections.

Answer (score 1):

If you select some features from map canvas, the following signal is emitted:
[selectionChanged](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsMapCanvas.html#a23fbdc9549eb365a6d063ee15efe3fa3)

So you just need to create function which calculate area and connect it to this signal.

Comment: Thanks, I will take a look at this signal and see how I get on!